# Keeping the same url parameters when user browse to other pages on the site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm interested in keeping the same url parameters the user already have, when he browses to other pages in my website.

For example if he enters through the link
`mysite.com/?phone=9384839484`, then any internal link on the site should redirect him to `mysite.com/internalpage?phone=9384839484`

The purpose is to track phone calls from each platform by showing them the same phone number everywhere on the site.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with apache / `.htaccess` / mod_rewrite (as you've tagged your question). You need to dynamically update the links in your HTML source (with whatever server-side scripting language you are using) as you serve the pages to the client.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol so your request implies some kind of session storage. `mod_rewrite` must be the most inadequate tool to accomplish that. You must certainly be using some client-side or server-side language to use the *phone* parameter which is possibly a much better fit.

Comment: _“by showing them the same phone number everywhere on the site”_ - then store it into the _session_ when they first enter your site using that initial URL containing the parameter …? Unless you have a very specific reason why this should be passed along via URL in the first place?